# Statically Display Excel drop-down boxes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-visio, presentations, data-validation

I'm looking to present an Excel questionnaire I have written to the board, via either paper or presentation slides. It uses a lot of drop-down boxes, and so I'm looking for any ideas on how one might go about showing the options for each response (from the drop-down boxes), without having to manually print screen a bunch of times and pasting the results into Visio.

Has anyone come across a nie easy, fast method of doing this?

Comment: How were you planning on giving the presentation?  Planning on presenting within excel or are you trying to generate images you can import into powerpoint or visio?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with Data validation drop downs.  Any chance of converting the dropdowns to ActiveX Controls?

Even the following code snippet fails:

```
Sub Foo()
    Range("C4").Select    'Assuming this is the cell containing the dropdown list
    Application.SendKeys "%{DOWN}", 1
    Range("C4:C10").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D16")
End Foo
```

It does cause the dropdown to appear, but the 'CopyPicture' methods copies the underlying cells, not the displayed dropdown.